# mysql select column from view problem

Tags: mysql, view

i create a view table like :

```
CREATE VIEW ViewManager AS
SELECT 
us.UserId AS 'Account Manager', .........
```

after that, when i run a query to select data from this view

like :

```
SELECT  'Account Manager' , .. from ViewManager
```

then the data i get in this column is the text **'Account Manager'** and not the value of the this columns.

Is there a way to solve this ?
Of course I can change the field name , but i want to know if there is another solution,

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks to escape column and table names.

```
SELECT `Account Manager` , .. from `ViewManager`
```